# Extract correct data of a file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, information-extraction

During an integration process with variable stepsize (in concrete, ode113 integrator is used) the position of a body is determined through its acceleration which is stored in a file along with time (i.e. two columns, one for time and the remaining for the acceleration). However, because of there are failed integration steps through the mentioned process, the file for the acceleration data has more rows than the corresponding one for the position data. How I could to extract the correct data of the acceleration data and create a new file for it with the same rows as the position data file?

Comment: No, it is an issue that I have found during my space simulator development.

Comment: If the integration fails what gets stored in the two columns (time/acceleration data)? Would there be duplicate times at all the failed steps?

Comment: Yes, there would be. In addition, because of the integrator is Adams-Bashforth-Moulton, for each time step there is a value for the predictor scheme and a value for the corrector scheme.

Comment: So you only have to consider rows with duplicate times for removal? And of those, the last would be the correct one, yes? So filter out all rows with duplicate times (except for the last).

Comment: The idea looks like easy but the code for it does not seem to be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the incorrect data always distributed in a logical way? You can create a search function, looking at the indices of the matrix. Thus cut out the correct data by copying them to a new variable of the now correct length. possibly expensive interms of run time and data storage but definately surefire.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was resolving my problem calculating the acceleration data using the position and velocity results obtained (i.e. I determined the acceleration two times) but this way of acting increases my runtime program.